# create a circle object and push them in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to create circles in canvas using fabric. Every click, there is a circle created. However, if the new circle created it will replace old circle. This my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-p1pspi?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.scss) demo.

**HTML**

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="400" >
  <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas!</p>
</canvas>
```

**TS**

```
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    fill: '#eef',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});
    var text = new fabric.Text(`${data.data.name}`, {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});
    this.group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
    left: event.e.offsetX,
    top: event.e.offsetY,
    angle: 0
});
console.log(this.group);
this.canvas.add(this.group);

this.canvas.setActiveObject(this.canvas.item[0]);
this.canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: I don't get what do you want? what is the problem? can you explain more?

Comment: Hi @AmirrezaNoori.., I've update my question with [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-p1pspi?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.scss) demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeatedly creating the `Canvas` object, which is likely resulting in the canvas element being drawn over multiple times in separate instances. That is, every new instance will only ever contain the most recent circle and will draw over the previous instance. What you want to do is create the instance once and then reference that instance each time moving forward.

In your code snippet above, it could look something like this:

```
// Ensures that the instance is only created once!
if(!this.canvas) {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
}

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    fill: '#eef',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

var text = new fabric.Text(`${data.data.name}`, {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

this.group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
    left: event.e.offsetX,
    top: event.e.offsetY,
    angle: 0
});

console.log(this.group);
this.canvas.add(this.group);

this.canvas.setActiveObject(this.canvas.item[0]);
this.canvas.renderAll();
```

I've even added relevant changes to your stackblitz project [in a fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal-zkpfmr?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts) to help illustrate how this could be accomplished.

Comment: It working like Cham.. Thank you so much you save my day..

Comment: Can I as one more question., How to prevent pop up modal open when I click on `circle `?

Comment: @Fash That's unfortunately beyond the scope of the original question and would thus violate the stackoverflow site guidelines. That said, please feel free to submit a separate question, including any information on different approaches you've considered and attempted to solve the problem. If I see it, then I'll be certain to take a look!

Comment: oo. okey.. i'm so sorry..